# GridView Filter issue with paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a `GridView` via a `ObjectDataSource`. I've also implemented some filter functions in terms of a `dropdown list` as well as a `textbox` to search. My code looks like this :

.aspx :

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AllowPaging="true"  PageSize="30" EmptyDataText="No data available" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="45%" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="100px" Width="40%" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="" >
                <ItemStyle Width="40%" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="100px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
         </Columns>

  </asp:GridView>

         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="Staff" SelectMethod="StaffData" />
```

Filter method :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Name")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Name LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Department")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Department LIKE '" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";

    }
```

As you can see, I have enabled  Paging in the GridView. Now my problem is: When I select a Filter and search by Department for example I get the results as expected. So as an example I have searched for the Media Department and 30 results are displayed on the page. The paging indicator at the bottom says there are 4 pages of results. If I now click on the second page I get to the second page of ALL the results in the GridView without the applied filter. So for whatever reason the filter is removed. Hope I've explained it alright.
Anybody has an idea how I could fix this?

**EDIT**
I have tried to make it work with `PageIndexChanging` like this :

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["test"] != null)
    {
        if ((bool)ViewState["test"] == true)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Name")
            {

                ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Name LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Department")
            {

                ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Department LIKE '" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";

            }

        }
    }

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState.Add("test", true);

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Name")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Name LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

    }
 else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Department")
            {

                ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Department LIKE '" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";

            }
  }
```

Comment: I struggled with the same issue for a while. Didn't find a working solution. Paging doesn't play all that well with filtering. Good luck on the quest.

Comment: @Sami see the Edit- got it to work with that if it helps you

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work with the above edit. It's not the prettiest solution but it works- Just posting this answer in case anybody else runs into the same problem.